# Attempting to create another database table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am weeks old in terms of Python programming and I am practicing what I am learning by creating simple applications that could benefit my work.

Here is the issue, I have a Tkinter app with one database table fully functioning, and I am trying to add another database table but have trouble figuring out how to add it (here's my attempt below).

```
import sqlite3


class LocatairesDatabase:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute(
            """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locataires (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nom text, prenom text, type text, bien text, email text, telephone text)""", """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locations (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, start_date text, end_date text, FOREIGN KEY (locataire_id) REFERENCES locataires(id))""")
        self.conn.commit()

    def fetch(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM locataires")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows
   
   def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

When I try to create the table as a second argument to the execute() method, I get an error (sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 148 supplied.). Would you please guide me to find a way to implement this? Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. Also show the code which causes the error, not a modified variant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MichaelButscher I have made the changes

Comment: This isn't the full traceback but anyway: You can't place multiple SQL statements in a single call to "execute". You need one "execute" call per statement.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for your reply again. I have tried to create the database table on another execute call but I got this error:  File "c:\Users\media store\Desktop\location\locataires_db.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.cur.execute(
sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown column "locataire_id" in foreign key definition

Comment: @Tobari Since you are not showing enough information to know how your full table looks it is difficult to assist you. You are also making multiple questions on the same thread. Anyway,  SQLLite is case sensitive, make sure locataire_id exist and that the case is the same as in the Database.

Comment: There is no column "locataire_id" in the table "locations". You have to add it to the list of columns of the table.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It has fixed my problem! I thought I created the column by specifying the foreign key. I cannot thank you enough I know I have not explained my problem very well because I am a beginner but you still were very understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think after you have created your first table you must commit it using "self.conn.commit()" and do the same for the second table you want to create

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have written the code but it does not seem to work as I got another error